# Update command fails. Can someone check my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (`custTAB`) which has some *zip* codes missing, but has  *city*, *state* names. I have a `zipTAB` which has a *city*, *state* and *zip* codes. My intent is to copy the missing zip codes from zipTAB to custTAB. However, for some reason my update doesn't work as intended. If there were 10K NULL cust_zips, after the update I get 20K NULL cust_zips. Can someone check what's going on? )

```
update custTAB 
   set cust_zip = (select zip 
                     from zipTAB 
                    where custTAB.cust_zip  is null and 
                          custTAB.cust_city   =  zipTAB.city and 
                          custTAB.cust_state  =  zipTAB.state 
                    limit 1 
                  );
```

Thanks.
PS: The row numbers are edited for easier reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try this one? you need to join the two tables:

```
UPDATE custTab a INNER JOIN zipTab b ON
        a.cust_city = b.city AND
        a.cust_state = b.state
SET a.cust_zip = b.zip
WHERE a.cust_zip IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can see that the number of changed rows are about an expected value. If you have time, could you explain what was wrong with my query and why yours worked?